# How to create tables using the column names of existing table?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a table x with 400 columns like xpk,x1,x2..x399 (where xpk is the primary key of the table).Based on a requirement I need to create a separate table for each column except for xpk.

To do this traditionally I would have to write 400 create statements. Can you please help me to achieve this using a procedure or dynamic sql?

I have tried something on the employees table just to give you an idea. But even in that I am getting errors.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE CURSOR COL_CUR IS
    select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
    NAMES user_tables.table_name%TYPE;
    SQL_STRING VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN

    OPEN COL_CUR;
    LOOP
      FETCH COL_CUR INTO NAMES;
      EXIT WHEN COL_CUR%NOTFOUND;
      SQL_STRING := 'CREATE TABLE :T_NAMES AS SELECT employee_id, :C_NAMES FROM EMPLOYEES';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STRING  USING NAMES,NAMES;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE COL_CUR;
END;
```

Required output:

First_name as a table having the following columns:

```
Employee_id  First_name
1234          Ashish
```

Similarly I want tables for other columns.

Answer (score 1):

We can't use bind variables in dynamic DDL.  You need to rewrite the  inner code like this:

```
SQL_STRING := 'CREATE TABLE '|| NAMES ||
              ' AS SELECT employee_id, '|| NAMES ||' FROM EMPLOYEES';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STRING;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE CURSOR COL_CUR IS
    select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES' and Column_name != 'employee_id';
    NAMES user_tables.table_name%TYPE;
    SQL_STRING VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN

    OPEN COL_CUR;
    LOOP
      FETCH COL_CUR INTO NAMES;
      EXIT WHEN COL_CUR%NOTFOUND;
      SQL_STRING := 'CREATE TABLE '|| NAMES ||
              ' AS SELECT employee_id, '|| NAMES ||' FROM EMPLOYEES';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STRING  USING NAMES,NAMES;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE COL_CUR;
END;
```